# java | мелкий вопрос по поводу метода equals

Tags: java, equals

Как реализованы методы по типу `equals`? Я понимаю, конечно же, что метод `equals` должен вызвать объект: собственно, в этом и вопрос. Как он так написан, что может быть вызван лишь объектом? Только сегодня что-то задумался. Если можно — пример, как реализовать подобную "фишку".

Если всё еще непонятно:

```
public class Main() {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        equals();  // error
        object.equals(...);  // всё нормально.
    }
}
```

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/168195/

Comment: эх, если бы мне еще кто-нить сказал что такое

Comment: this == object, каков смысл this?

Comment: Там написано же `вернет true лишь в одном случае — когда ссылки указывают на один и тот-же объект.` или читать не судьба?)  this указывает на самого себя.... то есть если this - это сам объект и object - он же - значит объекты равны (что логично)

Comment: Читать судьба, но this как-то сам по себе странный. То одно значение, то другое, вот и неуверен почему он там-то используется. Спасибо =)

Comment: что значит this то одно значение то другое? О_о

Comment: Не так выразился. Обычно новичкам не всегда говорят, каков смысл слова this. Я, как новичок - всегда думал что this может быть только в таком контексте "  this.object = object " (т.е. думал что this указывает экземпляр класса) и т.д. Про простое значение слова this я не знал. 
Скорее, "То одна роль, то другая"

Comment: но.... this действительно указывает на текущий экземпляр класса. ..... `this.object` - указывает на поле с именем `object` в данном классе... `this.object` никак не связано с просто `object`, если только его тип не `object` О_о

Comment: Судя по коду, у автора проблема с пониманием различия между методами класса (статическими) и методами экземпляра класса.

Answer (score 2):

Метод **equals** описан в классе **Object**. Так как все классы наследуются от **Object**, то метод **equals** есть у любого объекта.

В **Object** метод **equals** выглядит вот так

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

То есть по умолчанию объект равен только самому себе.

Многие классы переопределяют метод **equals**. Например класс **Long**

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Long) {
        return value == ((Long)obj).longValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

То есть два объекта типа **Long** равны, если они содержат одинаковое значение типа **long**.

Answer (score 1):

Автор почему-то поленился написать какая именно ошибка. Но очевидно, что нет такого метода `equals()`, есть `boolean equals(Object obj)`. И соответственно компилятор сообщит об этом. Трудно не заметить такую мессагу:

> Main.java:12: error: method equals in class Object cannot be applied to given types;
>   equals();
>   ^
>   required: Object
>   found: no arguments
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>   1 error

Вы для начала хотя бы с этим разобрались:)